# Query Vertica between dates from PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, vertica

I have Spark 1.6 running over Python 3.4, retrieve data from my Vertica database to work on it the below query,Spark DataFrames support predicate push-down with JDBC sources but term predicate is used in a strict SQL meaning. It means it covers only WHERE clause. Moreover it looks like it is limited to the logical conjunction (no IN and OR I am afraid) and simple predicates, it shows this error : java.lang.RuntimeException: Option 'dbtable' not specified

the DB contains massive data around 100 billions and I can't retrieve the data
and spark1.6 doesn't allow me to use query only dbtable as schema.table, and I got the below error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Option 'dbtable' not specified
```

```py
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

url = "*******"
properties = {"user": "*****", "password": "*******", "driver": "com.vertica.jdbc.Driver" }

df = sqlContext.read.format("JDBC").options(
    url = url,
    query = "SELECT date(time_stamp) AS DATE, (subscriber) AS IMSI, (server_hostname) AS WEBSITE, (bytes_in) AS DOWNLINK, (bytes_out) AS UPLINK,(connections_out) AS CONNECTION FROM traffic.stats WHERE DATE(time_stamp) between '2019-01-25' AND '2019-01-29'",
    **properties
).load()

df.show()
```

I have tried the below query with no result it takes long time without using limit function

```py
query = "SELECT date(time_stamp) AS DATE, (subscriber) AS IMSI, (server_hostname) AS WEBSITE, (bytes_in) AS DOWNLINK, (bytes_out) AS UPLINK,(connections_out) AS CONNECTION FROM traffic.stats WHERE date(time_stamp) between '2019-01-27' AND '2019-01-29'"
df = sqlContext.read.format("JDBC").options(
    url = url,
    dbtable="( " + query + " ) as temp",
    **properties
).load()
```

is it there anyway to read the data as above or read it as dataframe with specific query ?

I have tried to reduce the time by set more conditions and limitation , but its refused on $\conditions , even if remove the conditions its gives me "Subquery in FROM must have an alias" , this is the query:

```sql
SELECT min(date(time_stamp)) AS mindate,max(date(time_stamp)) AS maxdate,count (distinct date(time_stamp)) AS noofdays, (subscriber) AS IMSI, (server_hostname) AS WEBSITE, sum(bytes_in) AS DL, sum(bytes_out) AS UL, sum(connections_out) AS conn from traffic.stats where SUBSCRIBER like '41601%' and date(time_stamp) between '2019-01-25' and '2019-01-29'and signature_service_category = 'Web Browsing' and (signature_service_name = 'SSL v3' or signature_service_name = 'HTTP2 over TLS') and server_hostname not like '%.googleapis.%' and server_hostname not like '%.google.%' and server_hostname <> 'doubleclick.net'  and server_hostname <> 'youtube.com'  and server_hostname <> 'googleadservices.com'  and server_hostname <> 'app-measurement.com' and server_hostname <> 'gstatic.com' and server_hostname <> 'googlesyndication.com' and server_hostname <> 'google-analytics.com'  and server_hostname <> 'googleusercontent.com'  and server_hostname <> 'ggpht.com'  and server_hostname <> 'googletagmanager.com' and server_hostname is not null group by subscriber, server_hostname
```

Comment: How many rows is the traffic.stats table? How many rows, does the query (with the date range filter) return? How long does the query take when you execute it against Vertica directly?

Comment: its more than 100 billion , it takes more than an hour during the execution time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the query is taking more than an hour to filter between the date ranges, you should consider writing a projection.

```sql
CREATE PROJECTION traffic.status_date_range
(
  time_stamp,
  subscriber,
  server_hostname,
  bytes_in,
  bytes_out,
  connections_out
)
AS
  SELECT
    time_stamp,
    subscriber,
    server_hostname,
    bytes_in,
    bytes_out,
    connections_out
  FROM traffic.stats
  ORDER BY time_stamp
SEGMENTED BY HASH(time_stamp) ALL NODES;
```

Creating a query specific projection like this could add a significant amount of disk space, but if performance is really important to you, then it may be worth it.

I would also recommend partitioning the table if you haven't already done this. Depending on how many distinct dates you have in your traffic.stats table, you may not want to partition by day. Each partition creates at least 1 ROS container (and sometimes more). So if you have 1024 or more distinct dates then Vertica won't even let you partition by date in which case you could partition by month. If you are using Vertica 9, then you can take advantage of Hierarchal Partitioning (you can read about that [here](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Partitions/HierarchicalPartitioning.htm)).

I would caution that reorganizing a table after running the `ALTER TABLE` statement to add a partition clause would require a significant amount of disk space as Vertica writes data to new files. Once it is done, the table will take up pretty much the same amount of space as it does now, but while it is partitioning your disk space could grow quite large.

Comment: that was amazing thank you , I have edited my post could you please check the last phase ,thank you.

Comment: Please post the exact statement you use, and the full traceback that contains the $\conditions error. Thank you.

Comment: i have edit the question its on the last section ,when i try to run it return  ERROR: Syntax error at or near "\" , even if i remove the **\$condtion** , it returns "ERROR: Subquery in FROM must have an alias"

Comment: I'm still confused about `$\conditions`. You keep saying that you get errors regarding `$\conditions`, but I'm not seeing anything of the sort in the spark statements you are running or in the Vertica queries being executed. Please post the exact statement you are using that is throwing this error.